# Android: if/else trouble onPostExecute on a LoginActivity

Tags: android, json, if-statement, android-asynctask

I am just new in programming world with no experience. I am about to finish my Android project but my problem is: My toast message always says LOGIN FAILED even if I entered the correct username and password from my application. Please help me with the correct code!! (i am doing this for a long time)

Below is my login activity:

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            //three methods get called, first preExecture, then do in background, and once do
            //in back ground is completed, the onPost execute method will be called.

            /**
            * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
            * */
            boolean failure = false;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                String username = user.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();
                //int success;
                //String message =null;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pword", password));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");
                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                    return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return null;

            }
            /**
            * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
            * **/

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                //JSONObject json;
                // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
                pDialog.dismiss();

                //if (TAG_SUCCESS == null) {

                if (result.equals("success")) {
                //if (success.equals(success)) {
                    //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PortalContents.class);
                    finish();
                    //startActivity(i);
                    //return success;


                }

                else {
                    //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }

            }


        }

   }
```

This is the response from server when I login the correct uname and pword from logcat:

```
11-15 09:50:58.811: D/request!(865): starting ... 
11-15 09:51:02.041: D/Login attempt(865): {"success":"true"}
```

and this is the log if i log the wrong uname or pword:

```
11-15 09:57:23.352: D/request!(865): starting ... 
11-15 09:57:25.982: D/Login attempt(865): {"message":"Invalid username or password","success":"failed"}
```

- which looks like the server is responding correctly. However, the message toast from onPostExecute always responding as "LOGIN FAIL" even my login uname/pword is correct or wrong.

Comment: your `return null` in doInbackground.

Comment: @ Raghunandan: This is the response from server when I login the correct uname and pword from logcat: 11-15 09:50:58.811: D/request!(865): starting ... 11-15 09:51:02.041: D/Login attempt(865): {"success":"true"} and this is the log if i log the wrong uname or pword: 11-15 09:57:23.352: D/request!(865): starting ... 11-15 09:57:25.982: D/Login attempt(865): {"message":"Invalid username or password","success":"failed"} - which looks like the server is responding correctly. However, the message toast that appearing is "LOGIN FAIL" even my login uname/pword is correct or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return the server response.... return null, so the onPostExecute's result never will be "success".

You should return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: Thanks Alex, can you give me that right code base from my codes that I have created?

Comment: It's not that hard, you have to learn a little bit about Async tasks because i see you don't have a clue about how it is working... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html Also i already told what to do, but the "return" keyword before the json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: @ Alex, If I replace return null; with return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS); 
I am getting error on eclipse saying "json cannot be resolved"
Can you give me that right code base from my codes that I have created?

Comment: Yes, I still need to study about it. I will read this link that you gave.

Comment: @Hahn post your json and is your parsing json successfull?

Comment: @ Raghunandan yes the parsing is successful base on logcat. I am receiving acknowledgement from server

Comment: @Hahn if so post what you see in logcat. Will help solve your problem

Comment: @Hahn don't need to replace the return null, just add a return before the json.getString("..") i can't edit the code here but  Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                    return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: This is the response from server when I login the correct uname and pword from logcat:

11-15 09:50:58.811: D/request!(865): starting
...
11-15 09:51:02.041: D/Login attempt(865): {"success":"true"}

and this is the log if i log the wrong uname or pword:

11-15 09:57:23.352: D/request!(865): starting
...
11-15 09:57:25.982: D/Login attempt(865): {"message":"Invalid username or password","success":"failed"}


- which looks like the server is responding correctly. However, the message toast that appearing is "LOGIN FAIL"

even my login uname/pword is correct or wrong.

Comment: Yes because you are checking the json KEY instead of the json VALUE. uccess = Boolean.valueOf(json.getBoolean(TAG_SUCCESS)). Also in the onPost execute if (result.equals("true"))  instead of "success"

Comment: I will try that real quick...should I insert 

    Boolean success; ?

Comment: @Alex: I tried this code that you gave. The message toast is now responding right when I login the correct username and password but when I input the wrong uname and pass, it crshes...

logcat shows:

   11-15 12:41:44.115: W/System.err(1322): org.json.JSONException: Value failed at success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to boolean

11-15 12:41:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):  at com.hahndroid.allianceinmotion.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:171)

Comment: Yes my mistake, i assumed that if the login fails the success will be "false" not "failed". Lets forget the boolean approach. I think you edited the code in your question. Now it is almost correct, just change the onPost execute's if (result.equals("true")) and all should work.

Comment: @Alex: it is working now. On the final project I will replace that toast message "Login Successful with an Intent, so the user can access the portal. Thank you so much guys for your help.

Comment: @Alex, just a short follow up on this question... why is it when I use intent and put the web site on the next activity, it is not LOGGED in, it is just the web login page appears, not the content of the webpage when you successfully logged in.

Comment: @Hahn I follow your question and I am same code can you give proper code which works properly..I struck in login page..help me..I vote up

Answer (score 1):

You are returning null in your `doInBackground` and hence you always get Login Failed. You need to pass some `String` based on success/failure of your login.

Comment: Do you receive any acknowledgement from server when you `POST` to `LOGIN_URL` that whether the login was successful or not?

Comment: @ Apoorv, yes i am receiving acknowledgement base on logcat

Comment: @Hahn post the same here as part of your question.

Comment: @ ApoorThis is the response from server when I login the correct uname and pword from logcat: 

    11-15 09:50:58.811: D/request!(865): starting ... 
    11-15 09:51:02.041: D/Login attempt(865): {"success":"true"} 

and this is the log if i log the wrong uname or pword: 

    11-15 09:57:23.352: D/request!(865): starting ... 
    11-15 09:57:25.982: D/Login attempt(865): {"message":"Invalid username or password","success":"failed"} 

- which looks like the server is responding correctly. However, the message toast that appearing is "LOGIN FAIL" even my login uname/pword is correct or wrong.

Comment: Are you returning `String` as suggested by @Raghunandan in your `doYourBackground`?

Comment: yes it is getting correct values from the server in logcat. when my username and password is correct the response from server says success":"true" and if i login wrong server will respond as "message":"Invalid username or password","success":"failed" . However the message toast in onPostExecute always  says LOGIN FAIL.

Comment: I don't mean server response i mean the `String` that you are passing to `onPostExecute` check its value there not in `doInBackground`

Comment: @Apoorv I edited my code above. Please tell me if what is the mistake I have done.Appreciate your help.

Comment: Replace `return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);` with return json.getString("success");

Comment: I did but still experiencing the same problem

Comment: Replace `if (result.equals("success"))` with `if (result.equals("true"))`

Comment: @ Apoorv: I tried it.  The message toast is now responding right when I login the correct username and password but when I input the wrong uname and pass, it crshes... logcat shows: 11-15 12:41:44.115: W/System.err(1322): org.json.JSONException: Value failed at success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to boolean 11-15 12:41:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): at com.hahndroid.allianceinmotion.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.onPostExecute(LoginAct‌​ivity.java:171) –

Answer (score 0):

You return null in `doInbackground`. The result of `doInbackground` is a param to `onPostExecute`. You need to return a `String`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Change to

```
 String success =json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

 return sucess;
```

Also change

```
case R.id.btn_login:
            if (isInternetPresent) {
                new AttemptLogin().execute(); 
            }else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "NO NETWORK CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
 break;
```

Edit :

```
    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            String success =null;

            try {
                // Building Parameters

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pword", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                success = json.getString("success");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return success;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan, I tried this code below but I am experiencing runtime error

11-13 20:18:15.659: E/AndroidRuntime(4006):  at com.hahndroid.allianceinmotion.LoginActivity$AttemptLogin.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:169)


    String success = null;  // I added this

    String success =json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    return sucess;

Comment: @Hahn check if success is null or not

Comment: @ Raghunandan   this is the json resp

{
    "success": "failed",
    "message": "Invalid username or password"
}

Comment: @Hahn check the edit in my post now. your login credentials are not right

Comment: I tried your edit code but still even if my uname ang pword is right ,,, the message toast says login failed. but on the logcat, the response from server is right ang the login is successful

Comment: @Hahn what you posted the json says your login credentials are not right. You got `"success": "failed"`. As far as the code is concerned to the question asked this is the solution. What you sent and what you receive is for you to ponder over and set it right. May be you sent wrong data or may be your server respond data is wrong. How can i tell what is wrong

Comment: @ Raghunandan: This is the response from server when I login the correct uname and pword from logcat: 11-15 09:50:58.811: D/request!(865): starting ... 11-15 09:51:02.041: D/Login attempt(865): {"success":"true"} and this is the log if i log the wrong uname or pword: 11-15 09:57:23.352: D/request!(865): starting ... 11-15 09:57:25.982: D/Login attempt(865): {"message":"Invalid username or password","success":"failed"} - which looks like the server is responding correctly. However, the message toast that appearing is "LOGIN FAIL" even my login uname/pword is correct or wrong. –